# Generate a table in modal box on submitting a form based on the inputs given in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, modal-dialog

As the problem statement stated I would like to generate a table inside modal box on submitting the form, based on the inputs given in form. And number of rows ma vary as per the input given.

[Click here](https://pvbscc.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: What you have tried yet in code?

Comment: I am not getting where to start!

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ryjRdY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the #myModal div after the form is submitted.

Use this Javascript code.

```
$(function(){
    $('#form1').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if($('#form1')[0].checkValidity() ){
        zinPrefix='<div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="close">&times;</button><h4 class="modal-title">Results</h4></div><div class="modal-body">';
        zinSuffix='</div><div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button></div></div></div>';
        zinTable="";
        var $inputs = $('#form1 :input');
        //var values = {};
        $inputs.each(function() {
        val = $(this).val();
        if(val!="")
              zinTable += val +" \t | \t ";
        });
        zinStr = zinPrefix + zinTable + zinSuffix;
        $("#myModal").html(zinStr);
        $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
    }
    });
});
```

Working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9r786Lnv/)